# Invalid operands to binary expression "`const Foo` and `const Foo`, no matching call to sort

Tags: c++, sorting

I am trying to sort a vector of a class, `Foo`. In my `Foo` class, I have overriden the `<` operator. I pass in iterators to the sort function of a `vector<Foo> foo_vec` like so: `sort(foo_vec.begin(), foo_vec.end())`, and I have `using namespace std;`. What could be causing this error?

More details:

The override, in `Foo.cpp`

```cpp
bool Foo::operator <(Foo const & b) {
    if (cost < b.cost) return true; 
    else return false;
}
```

The call, after including the appropriate files:

```cpp
vector<Foo> children = b.gen(b); // This returns a Foo vector
sort(children.begin(), children.end()); // Gives error.
```

Error message:

```
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:715:71: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const Foo' and 'const Foo')
    bool operator()(const _T1& __x, const _T1& __y) const {return __x < __y;}
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. There isn't enough information to answer your question.

Comment: Okay, I added some more.

Comment: Your `operator<` needs to be marked as `const`: `bool Foo::operator <(Foo const & b) const`

Comment: Do you mean `bool Foo::operator <(const Foo& b) const {`?

Comment: Wow, that solved it @tadman . Why does that extra const have to be there? Same to you Remy Lebeau. Can I get an explanation? I'm a bit confused on the "why"

Comment: @LukeAnglin ""*Why does that extra const have to be there?*" - see the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::sort()` is internally dereferencing the iterators and passing the `Foo` objects to a comparator (likely [`std::less`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less)) that is taking the `Foo` objects by `const` reference.  However, your `operator<` is not marked as `const`, so it can't be called on `const Foo` objects, only on non-const `Foo` objects.  You need to mark it as `const` (and should anyway, since it does not modify any member data of the `Foo` objects), eg:

```cpp
class Foo {
public:
    ...
    bool operator <(Foo const &) const; // <-- note the *trailing* const!
    ...
};

bool Foo::operator <(Foo const & b) const { // <-- note the *trailing* const!
    return (cost < b.cost);
}
```