# XCode: Error with comparisons "Invalid operands to binary expression ('const class' and 'const class')

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, overloading

I have an idea as to where this issue is coming from so I will try to explain it as best as I can.

Essentially, I am trying to make a card game where I have two classes Player and Card. The Card class is included within Player as each player has a vector of Card objects to simulate a players current hand.

However, I have a function to attempt to sort the players hand in order of the value that I have assigned them. I am using algorithms sort function in the player class and have overloaded the '>' operator for the card class.

Player sort function:

```
void player::sort_hand() {
    sort(current_hand.begin(), current_hand.end());
}
```

Card '>' overload:

```
bool card::operator<(const card &rhs) {
    if (this->value < rhs.value) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I am coding this in xcode and the errors I receive are "Invalid operand to binary expression and "no matching function call for ___Sort3" and so on. My main concern is that I was able to compile this code on Visual Studio Code and repl.it. XCode is the first time I've received an error so I am worried something may actually be wrong here.

Additionally, I ran across something called circular referencing while trying to include Card class within Player but was left confused regardless despite getting it to work, any tips towards addressing this in the future would be appreciated.

[image: errors]

Comment: Perhaps not related to your issue, but hard to tell without the full errors you're getting, but `operator<` should generally be const. ex: `bool card::operator<(const card &rhs) const { ... }` It would be useful to see a [mcve] and the complete errors.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but whenever you something like `if (condition) return true; return false;` it can be shortened to `return condition;`.

Comment: Unrelated: Simplify: `bool card::operator<(const card &rhs) { return value < rhs.value }` - the `if`...`else` part is just confusing.

Comment: @RetiredNinja , I was able to fix all of the errors by simply adding the const you suggested. I'll make sure to remember that for the future.

I did add a screenshot of all the errors in case you'd like to take a look anyway.

Comment: @TedLyngmo , I'll go ahead and do this thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: From [ask]: "**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.**"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid operands to binary expression "\`const Foo\` and \`const Foo\`, no matching call to sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66607527/invalid-operands-to-binary-expression-const-foo-and-const-foo-no-matching)